# How to make a python Script wait until download has finished

Tags: python, download, zip, sequential, shutil

My Script downloads a zipfile, exctracts the relevant parts replaced files and folders etc. It used to work flawlessly, for some reason its has now decided to stop working and only partly downloads the zipfile, and of course, as the zipfile is incomplete I get an error, saying the downloaded file is not a zipfile. my script is as follows.

```
def downloadupdate():
    xbmcgui.Dialog().ok(
        "[B][COLOR white]Daily Updater[/B][/COLOR]",
        "Favourites and some software will now update",
        "Elements of your system will be cleaned",
        "Daily Update will take at most 2 minutes")
    #ONLY HAVE THE SUPER FAVOURITES FOLDER IN THE ZIPFILE!!
    url = 'http://x.com/x/x/Super Favourites.zip'
    destination = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super Favourites.zip')
    favzip = urllib.urlopen(url)
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Downloading new updates, PLEASE WAIT,()")
    with open(xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super Favourites.zip'), "wb") as zipFile:
        zipFile.write(favzip.read())
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Download Complete, Please wait,()")
    time.sleep(5)
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Updating Click and Play channels, Please wait,()")
    updatezip = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/iupdatefix/Super Favourites.zip')
    extractupdate = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.super.favourites/')
    oldfav = xbmc.translatePath('special://home/userdata/addon_data/plugin.program.super.favourites/Super Favourites')
    yeszip = os.path.exists(updatezip)
    time.sleep(5)
    if yeszip:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Removing previous, Please wait,()")
        shutil.rmtree(oldfav, ignore_errors=False)
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Updating, now,()")
        gh = open(updatezip, 'rb')
        zp = zipfile.ZipFile(gh)
        zp.extractall(extractupdate)
        gh.close()
        time.sleep(3)
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(updated, Now Checking sd,()")
        # put this command at the end of whole script --->>>os.remove(updatezip)
    else:
        xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Update file Corrupt, Please try again,()")
```

Comment: `favzip.read()` waits for download. But if you get error then problem is with connection and you may have to start downloading from beginnig. Use `try/except`

Comment: furas could you please explain how i might use it in this example as Id like to try it out.

Comment: Python doc: [8. Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved, It was not the code. It was the hosting service, I had to reset the File permissions on the server and after that all works perfectly again.